# Source Version Control & Repositories for Xcode & Cocoa - A few simple Questions

Tags: xcode, version-control, repository

I find myself working on a HUGE project (which I myself started from scratch a year ago or so) and **I'm having some trouble keeping track of the changes, or find myself creating countless copies of the codebase** (*and I literally mean "copies" - take the whole code folder and paste it like `"MyApp-1.2.23-Mar2012"`, `"MyApp-1.3.1-Apr2012"`, etc; sounds silly?*).

***NOTE :*** Nobody else works on that codebase; so there's really no need that there is some remote repository or anything like that; all I need is 100% local.

I'm thinking that maybe I should use some Source Control Management system.

- Would that be the right thing for me? And if so, could you explain me
  one or two practical things on how this technology is working?
- Also, since I've had an extensive look into the documentation (and I
  still have no clue as to how to go about this), how could I setup
  this whole thing in an **already existing** Xcode 4.2 project (on
  Snow Leopard, if that makes any difference)?

Comment: Definitely go for it. I recommend git (and GitHub and Gitbox). It definitely takes some learning and getting used to, but it's worth the effort. Also if it's just you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1: Yes it's the right thing.  The important features I get from a source code control system are:

- snapshotting.  I can commit when I have finished something important and if I screw up the code base after that I can simply throw away all the changes I have made since the last snapshot and start again.
- branching.  If you release v1.0 of your application you can branch v2.0 to work on new features.  You can then maintain v1.0, making fixes and *backport* changes between the v1.0 and v2.0 codebases without introducing the new features into v1.0.
- safety.  My git repos are on my Linux server which has a hardware Raid-5 disk array, not the silly little 2.5" disk in my MacBookPro.
- change tracking.  I have integrated my Bugzilla and Git repos so that Bugzilla tickets track the git changes so I can see what code changes were made to fix a bug or introduce a new feature.

(there are umteen other features of git you'll get that I take for granted and have forgotten to mention).

2: From the documentation side of things you will need to read [The Git Community Book](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://book.git-scm.com/&ei=r02ET9nkBsLq8QP04JTwBw&usg=AFQjCNHtsfmxgE4MFt_0itiBb11OoP-ilw)

3: If you already have an Xcode project you can simply check that into Git and it *should* work straight out-of-the-box.  There will be one or two Xcode-related files you should exclude from git that are not meant to be tracked, but if it's just you working on it then don't worry about it until someone else joins the team.

Bottom Line: Once you have learnt how to use it you won't regret it and will wonder why you've never used a source code control system before.

Comment: Also, while the questioner says he doesn't need anything remote, it's easy to create a GitHub repository, and push changes there as a backup.